# how to filter mysql query results I am creating chat app i need last message result based on loggedin user

Tags: php, mysqli

I need logged in user all last messages if he/she sent OR received to any one

```
SELECT chat.id, chat.sender_id,chat.receiver_id,us.user_nicename as    sender_name, u.user_nicename as reciver_name,(SELECT v.message FROM wp_vendor_customer_chat as v where v.id=MAX(chat.id)) as message,chat.sent_date 

FROM wp_vendor_customer_chat as chat 
left join wp_users us on chat.sender_id = us.id 
left join wp_users u on chat.receiver_id = u.id 
WHERE receiver_id=1 OR sender_id=1 
GROUP BY chat.sender_id, chat.receiver_id

['sqlquery']https://hagglerplanet.jkssoftsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Untitled.png
```

Comment: add in order by sent_date?

Comment: Please clarify your question: What specific messages do you need? Based on your question right now, the query would be `SELECT * FROM wp_vendor_customer_chat WHERE receiver_id=1 OR sender_id=1 ORDER BY sent_date DESC`

Comment: You should store date and time of message sent and get them with `order by` clause.

Comment: I want to fetch logged in user last messages like : if he/she sent last message 02/01/2019 11:00:30 am then get this message
OR if anyone other sent message to logged in user then this message fetch reject the logged in user last message

This is my chat table 
     [chat table]https://hagglerplanet.jkssoftsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/chat.png
if loggedin user

Comment: This is my chat table      [chat table] https://hagglerplanet.jkssoftsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/chat-1.png

Here is duplicate records with every other user because single user message multiple time to same user so I used group by and order_by sent date not working it sort retrieved results

Answer (score 0):

I have found to solution of my issue.

```
 SELECT wp_vendor_customer_chat.*,us.user_nicename as sender_name, u.user_nicename as reciver_name FROM wp_vendor_customer_chat
left join wp_users us on wp_vendor_customer_chat.sender_id = us.id
left join wp_users u on wp_vendor_customer_chat.receiver_id = u.id
WHERE wp_vendor_customer_chat.id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id) AS last_msg_id 
    FROM wp_vendor_customer_chat WHERE `receiver_id` = ".$vendor_id." OR `sender_id` = ".$vendor_id." 
    GROUP BY IF(`sender_id` =".$vendor_id.", `receiver_id`, `sender_id`)
)
```

I have posted the solution because if anyone facing same problem